# pandas categorize a column

Tags: python, pandas

```
    other    x    y    z
1       x  NaN  NaN  NaN
21      z  NaN  NaN  NaN
71      y  NaN  NaN  NaN
2       x  NaN  NaN  NaN
22      z  NaN  NaN  NaN
72      y  NaN  NaN  NaN
3       x  NaN  NaN  NaN
23      z  NaN  NaN  NaN
73      y  NaN  NaN  NaN
60      x  NaN  NaN  NaN
90      z  NaN  NaN  NaN
80      y  NaN  NaN  NaN
91      z  NaN  NaN  NaN
64      x  NaN  NaN  NaN
64      y  NaN  NaN  NaN
155     x  NaN  NaN  NaN
165     y  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

how to make each entry of 'other' set 1 to the corresponding column and the rest to zero?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html). In your case, with the `x`, `y` and `z` columns already existing, you can do:

```
df[['x', 'y', 'z']] = pd.get_dummies(df.other)

>>> df
    other  x  y  z
1       x  1  0  0
21      z  0  0  1
71      y  0  1  0
2       x  1  0  0
22      z  0  0  1
72      y  0  1  0
3       x  1  0  0
23      z  0  0  1
73      y  0  1  0
60      x  1  0  0
90      z  0  0  1
80      y  0  1  0
91      z  0  0  1
64      x  1  0  0
64      y  0  1  0
155     x  1  0  0
165     y  0  1  0
```

One nice thing about this is that you don't really have to have your `x` `y` `z` column pre-made (if you don't have them already). Assuming your dataframe was just your `other` column, you can just do the follwoing, which means if you have any other values besides `x`, `y` and `z`, it will create new "dummy" columns for them too:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.other)], axis=1)
```

Which results in the same final dataframe in your case